# footer at the bottom with horizontal line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put footer at the bottom with a horizontal line just above the footer. But I am not even able to get footer at the bottom. Tried many posts and blogs but I am missing out on something. I am using the base of some blog to create the signup page.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/750h2crz/)

#### html

```
    <div id="header">

    </div>

    <div id="main"> 
    <div id="container">

  <form action="index.html" method="post">

    <p id="form_title" style='color:#808080'>Create an Account</p>

    <fieldset>
      <legend style="color:#585858">Get started with Your Profile</legend>
      <label for="name" style='color:#808080;font-size:14px'>CUSTOM NAME</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" style="color:#404040">


      <label for="type" style='color:#808080;font-size:14px'>TYPE</label>
      <select id="sel-type" name="type">

        <option value="frontend_developer">Front-End Developer</option>
        <option value="php_developor">PHP Developer</option>
        <option value="python_developer">Python Developer</option>
        <option value="rails_developer"> Rails Developer</option>
        <option value="web_designer">Web Designer</option>
        <option value="WordPress_developer">WordPress Developer</option>


    </select>
    <label for="type" style='color:#808080;font-size:14px'>REGION</label>
    <select id="sel-region" name="region">

        <option value="frontend_developer">Front-End Developer</option>
        <option value="php_developor">PHP Developer</option>
        <option value="python_developer">Python Developer</option>
        <option value="rails_developer"> Rails Developer</option>
        <option value="web_designer">Web Designer</option>
        <option value="WordPress_developer">WordPress Developer</option>


    </select>


    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Create Profile</button>
  </form>



    </div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
    <a href="About">About</a>
    <a href="info.com">Instructions</a>



<a href="tt.com">Encountered an issue?</a>  
</div>
```

#### css

```
*, *:before, *:after {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 }

body {
 font-family: 'Lato';
 background-color: #E8E8E8;

}

#header {
   width:100%;
   background-color: #27272D;
   height: 50px ;
   border:1px solid;
   position:relative;

}
#main{
   border:1px solid;

   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}

#container{

    margin-top: 100px;
    border:1px;
}

  form {
   max-width: 300px;
   margin: 10px auto;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   background-color: white;
   border:1px;
     }

  #form_title {
    margin: 10px 0 30px 15px;
    font-size:20px;
   }

 input[type="text"],
 select {
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
   border: none;
   font-size: 16px;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0;
   outline: 0;
   padding: 15px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #e8eeef;
   color: #8a97a0;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

   input[type="text"]{
      border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
     -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     height:44px;
     font-size: 14px;
      }


  select {
   padding: 6px;
   height: 44px;
   border-radius: 2px;
  }

 button {

   color: #FFF;
   background-color: #13ABAF;
   font-size: 14px;
   text-align: center;
   font-style: normal;
   border-radius: 5px;
   width: 96%;
   height:44px;
   border: 1px solid;
   border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   }

  fieldset {

    border: none; 
  }

  legend {
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
  }

  label {
   display: block;
   margin-bottom: 8px;
  }

  label.light {
   font-weight: 300;
   display: inline;
  }



  #horizontal-line{ 

     display: block;
     margin-top:100px;
     margin-bottom: 60px;
     width:96%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     border-style: inset;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-color: #F0F0F0;


     } 

    #footer {
     position : absolute;
     bottom : 0;
     height:60px;
     margin-top : 40px;
     text-align: center ;
     font-size: 10px ;
     font-family: 'Lato' ;
     }

    @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

    form {
      max-width: 480px;
     }

 }
```

Comment: Please try my answer. Check whether it is the required output or not. Thankyou ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `position: absolute` in your style:

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    /* ... */
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/750h2crz/2/

Comment: But when I try to put a horizontal line just over the footer, UI scatters with footer over the horizontal line.

Comment: Add a `border-top` and a `padding-top` properties to control the border a the separation respectively.

Answer (score 3):

For your css, try

```
#footer {
    position: relative; 
    ...
}
```

Also for the horizontal line just use

```
<hr>
```

html tag above footer

(sorry about that, my editing looks awkward because stackoverflow prints out a horizontal line whenever I use that tag)

Also its more simple and if you want minimal changes to css.

http://jsfiddle.net/750h2crz/7/

Answer (score 2):

put this in your css, and use a border instead of a horizontal line.

```
    footer {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0;
       height: 60px;
       border-top-width: 5px;
       border-top-style: solid;
       border-top-color: #FFF;
    }
```

Comment: removing position:absolute worked with border-top-xxxx but can I put some padding between the border and the text? UPDATE : padding-top will do the job.

Comment: you can mess with the line-height property, or the padding-top property

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use separate  tag   for footer sec  and use Horizontal Rule tag

```
<div id="footer">
                <hr>
   <footer>
           <a href="About">About</a>
           <a href="info.com">Instructions</a>



           <a href="tt.com">Encountered an issue?</a>  
  <footer>
</div>
```

Thx

Comment: I actually appreciate this answer. It is simple. If what you looking for this simple and this will definitely workout like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

updated your css with

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%; /* fill the whole width of the screen */
    border-top:1px solid #aaa; /* you can change to whatever color you want */
    padding-top:10px; /* add some spacing between line and links/text */
    background:#fff; /* this is important otherwise your background will be transparent, change the color based on your needs */
    /* ... your other properties */
}
```

Also updated you body styling with some padding at the bottom to offset the footer

```
body {
    /* ... your other properties */
    padding-bottom:65px;
}
```